Zoom Video SDK - Unable to render more than 4 videos with SharedArrayBuffer enabled on Chrome
Video SDK Type and Version
Zoom Video SDK 1.10.8 for Web https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/web/get-started/
Description
I am unable to render more than 4 videos in my Chrome (123.0.6312.106) browser.
It works fine for Firefox 124.0.2
I have enabled SAB like the below in my SvelteKit server
response.headers.set('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
response.headers.set('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');

SAB Verification:
self.crossOriginIsolated is true in the console
Still, I am unable to subscribe to more than 4 videos. I have also set enforceMultipleVideos: false.
Error?
subscribe video counts greater than maximum size (4)
How To Reproduce
Windows, Chrome 123.0.6312.106

Enable SAB like this

export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    const cookieString = event.request.headers.get('cookie');
    const user = await getAPIClient(fetch).getUser(cookieString);
    event.locals = { user, token: getTokenFromCookie(cookieString) };
    if (!canAccessEndpoint(user, event.url.pathname)) {
        error(403, 'Unauthorized access for server endpoint');
    }

    const response = await resolve(event);

    setCMIdCookie(event, response);

    response.headers.set('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
    response.headers.set('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');

    return response;
}


Create a canvas to paint all videos

<canvas id="participant-videos-canvas" width="1692" height="1285"></canvas>

<style>
    #participant-videos-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>


Init zoom using this function

async init() {
        await this.client.init('en-US', 'Global', { patchJsMedia: true, enforceMultipleVideos: false });
    }


Render all videos on an event

attachEventListeners() {
        this.client.on('peer-video-state-change', async () => {
            function sleep(ms) {
                return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
            }

            await sleep(5000); // Sleep for 5 seconds

            const participants = this.client.getAllUser();
            const layout = getVideoLayout(1692, 1285, participants.length);

            layout.forEach((cell, index) => {
                this.stream.renderVideo(
                    document.querySelector('#participant-videos-canvas'),
                    participants[index].userId,
                    cell.width,
                    cell.height,
                    cell.x,
                    cell.y,
                    cell.quality
                );
            });
        });


Error on console "subscribe video counts greater than maximum size (4)"

Referencing sample app (https://github.com/zoom/videosdk-web-sample) ,
I am using the same headers method for enabling SAB. And using the same canvas to render all videos. I don't see what am I missing here.

Hey @Harshit Bhatt, can you run the stream.isSupportMultipleVideos() function? Also, can you share the Windows device details?

You can disable the limit. I think Zoom is somehow detecting that you are on a mobile,. As such, even if you enable the headers, it will still be limited to four videos.
To fix this, disable the render limits by calling .init like so:
client.init({
  enforceMultipleVideos: { disableRenderLimits: true }
});

For for information, see the Zoom Developers documentation.
